# Recommended pattern to implement JSONAPI filter with query params in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, json-api

I spent a chunk of time yesterday trying to include filter (reflecting the [JSONAPI spec](http://jsonapi.org/recommendations/#filtering)) in the query params of part of an Ember app. With Ember Data it is easy enough to pass a filter array to an endpoint, the problem I have is reflecting that filter array in the query params for a particular route. Note: other, non array, query params are working fine.

TL;DR I have tried various options without success and have a solution that really feels unsatisfactory and not at all DRY. I figure that many others must have tackled this problem and have surely found a better solution. Read on for details of what I have tried so far.

I started with something like this (I initially assumed it would work having read the [Ember docs on query params](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/query-params/)):

Controller:

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';

export default Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['sort', 'filter'],
  sort: 'id',

  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.set('filter', []);
  },
});
```

Route:

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  queryParams: {
    filter: {
      refreshModel: true
    },
    sort: {
      refreshModel: true
    }
  },

  model(params) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(params)); // filter is always []
    return this.get('store').query('contact', params);
  }
});
```

Acceptance Test (this was just a proof of concept test before I started on the more complex stuff):

```
  test('visiting /contacts with query params', async function(assert) {
    assert.expect(1);
    let done = assert.async();

    server.createList('contact', 10);

    server.get('/contacts', (schema, request) => {
      let params = request.queryParams;

      assert.deepEqual(
        params,
        {
          sort: '-id',
          "filter[firstname]": 'wibble'
        },
        'Query parameters are passed in as expected'
      );
      done();
      return schema.contacts.all();
    });

    await visit('/contacts?filter[firstname]=wibble&sort=-id');
  });
```

No matter how I tweaked the above code, params.filter was always [] in the Route model function.

I have searched around for best-practice on what would seem to be a common use case, but have not found anything recent. [sarus' solution here from Nov 2015](https://gist.github.com/machty/8167051) works, but means that every possible filter key has to be hardcoded in the controller and route, which seems far from ideal to me. Just imagine doing that for 20 possible filter keys! Using sarus' solution, here is code that works for the above acceptance test but as I say imagine having to hardcode 20+ potential filter keys:

Controller:

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';

export default Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['sort',
    { firstnameFilter: 'filter[firstname]' }
  ],
  sort: 'id',
  firstnameFilter: null,

  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
  }
});
```

Route:

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  queryParams: {
    firstnameFilter: {
      refreshModel: true
    },
    sort: {
      refreshModel: true
    }
  },

  model(params) {
    if (params.firstnameFilter) {
      params.filter = {};
      params.filter['firstname'] = params.firstnameFilter;
      delete params.firstnameFilter;
    }
    return this.get('store').query('contact', params);
  }
});
```

I hope there's a better way!

Comment: `but means that every possible filter key has to be hardcoded in the controller and route` yes! At some point you need a list of all filters. You also probably need that for your UI anyway. Just have the list on one single point. Also maybe have a look at `ember-parachute`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have the requirement to support dynamic filter fields, @jelhan has provided a really good answer to this question already.

If you do need to support dynamic filter fields read on.

First of all, credit should go to @jelhan who put me on the right track  by mentioning the possibility of serializing the application URL with JSON.stringify() and encodeURIComponent() together.

Here's example code with this working...

Controller:

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';

export default Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['sort', {
    filter: {
      type: 'array'
    }
  }],

  sort: 'id',

  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.set('filter', []);
  },
});
```

Route (no changes required):

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  queryParams: {
    filter: {
      refreshModel: true
    },
    sort: {
      refreshModel: true
    }
  },

  model(params) {
    return this.get('store').query('contact', params);
  }
});
```

Acceptance Test:

```
  test('visiting /contacts with query params', async function(assert) {
    assert.expect(1);
    let done = assert.async();

    server.createList('contact', 10);

    server.get('/contacts', (schema, request) => {
      let params = request.queryParams;

      assert.deepEqual(
        params,
        {
          sort: '-id',
          "filter[firstname]": 'wibble',
          "filter[lastname]": 'wobble'
        },
        'Query parameters are passed in as expected'
      );
      done();
      return schema.contacts.all();
    });

    // The filter is represented by a Javascript object
    let filter = {"firstname":"wibble", "lastname":"wobble"};

    // The object is converted to a JSON string and then URI encoded and added to the application URL 
    await visit('/contacts?sort=-id&filter=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(filter)));
  });
```

Great! This test passes. The filter defined in the application URL is passed through to the Route. The Route's model hook makes a JSONAPI request with the filter correctly defined. Yay!

As you can see, there's nothing clever there. All we need to do is set the filter in the correct format in the application URL and the standard Ember Query Params setup will just work with dynamic filter fields.

But how can I update the filter query param via an action or link and see that reflected in the application URL and also make the correct JSONAPI request via the Route model hook. Turns out that's easy too:

Example Action (in controller):

```
changeFilter() {
  let filter = {
    firstname: 'Robert',
    lastname: 'Jones',
    category: 'gnome'
  };

  // Simply update the query param `filter`. 
  // Note: although filter is defined as an array, it needs to be set
  //  as a Javascript object to work
  // this.set('filter', filter); - this seems to work but I guess I should use transitionToRoute
  this.transitionToRoute('contacts', {queryParams: {filter: filter}});
}
```

For a link (say you want to apply a special filter), you'll need a controller property to hold the filter, we'll call it `otherFilter` and can then reference that in the `link-to`:

Example Controller property (defined in init):

```
init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.set('filter', []);    
    this.set('otherFilter', {occupation:'Baker', category: 'elf'});
}
```

Example link-to:

```
{{#link-to 'contacts' (query-params filter=otherFilter)}}Change the filters{{/link-to}}
```

There you have it!

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to represent filter values in applications URL the same way as they must be for backend call to be JSON API complaint. Therefore I would not use that format for application URLs.

If you don't have the requirement to support dynamic filter fields, I would hard code all of them to have nice URLs like `/contacts?firstname=wibble&sort=-id`.

Your code would look like this, if you like to support filtering for `firstname` and `lastname`:

```
// Controller
import Controller from '@ember/controller';

export default Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['sort', 'page', 'firstname', 'lastname'],
  sort: 'id',
});

// Route
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  queryParams: {
    firstname: {
      refreshModel: true
    },
    lastname: {
      refreshModel: true
    }
    sort: {
      refreshModel: true
    }
  },

  model({ firstname, lastname, sort, page }) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(params)); // filter is always []
    return this.get('store').query('contact', {
      filter: {
        firstname,
        lastname
      },
      sort,
      page
    });
  }
});
```

If you have to support dynamic filter fields, I would represent the filter object in application URL. For serialization you could use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) together. The URL would then look like `/contacts?filter=%7B%22firstname%22%3A%22wibble%22%7D&sort=-id`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond so thoroughly. Not including filter in the application URL would be the way to go if I didn't want to be able to handle dynamic filter fields. However, I would like to support dynamic filter fields, so your last paragraph has me intrigued. Since I posted the original question, I've been trying a few other options without success. Would you be able to flesh out where you would use `JSON.stringify()` and `encodeURIComponent` to update the URL? Thanks again.

Comment: Actually, I think I might have it sussed... I'll continue working on it tomorrow.